# xmin and cmin column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

When we create a table some of the system columns are implicitly defined by the system. So those names cannot be used as names of user
defined columns. The following is the columns which comes under system functions.

```
    i) xmin
   ii) cmin
```

What is the use of the above two columns and what are the information stored in this column.

Answer (score 1):

A look at [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) will prove to be informative.

> `cmin`
>
> The command identifier (starting at zero) within the inserting transaction.

...

> `xmin`
>
> The identity (transaction ID) of the inserting transaction for this row version. (A row version is an individual state of a row; each update of a row creates a new row version for the same logical row.)

If you want to know the internal details of how it all works start by reading the concurrency control and MVCC chapter of the manual. Then the source code if you need more detail.